# Rails updating morris.js data dynamically with coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, coffeescript, morris.js

in my Rails app I have a morris.js line chart that works perfectly fine on initial page load. What I'm now trying to accomplish is dynamically updating this chart when certain best_in_place fields in a table are updated (via `ajax:success`).

Updating a morris.js chart requires passing in a new array of hashes such as (in my case): `[{"month":"2014-05","cashposition":3},{"month":"2014-06","cashposition":1}]`. My model_method `cash_position` creates this just fine.

Here is the problem. In my `ajax:success` function in CoffeeScript I am having difficulty accessing the array of hashes from my model method `cash_position`. It may be more correct to say this array of hashes is not converting to json correctly.

I've set up a controller route `/cash_position` to render the array of hashes as json but the json renders like this:

`[{&quot;month&quot;=&gt;&quot;2015-04&quot;, &quot;cashposition&quot;=&gt;11}`

This delivers one object instead of an array of hashes that is needed, so the chart ignores it.

How do I access the method's results as an array of hashes? FYI I have successfully updated the chart by hand-typing a manual array of hashes into the below `.data()`, so I'm confident the sole issue is simply down to accessing this array of hashes and how it converts to json.

**static_pages.coffee**

```
$('.update-percent').on 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    data = $.ajax({url: "/payment_schedules/cash_position.json"})
    console.log(data)
    window.lineChart.setData(data)
```

**`console.log` output on `data`**

`responseText` displays a singular object with the improper json output described above, instead of an array of hashes.

**Updated with controller code**

**controller**

```
...
def cash_position
    @payment_schedule = PaymentSchedule.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Updated with cash_position.json.erb view template**

```
`<%= @payment_schedule.cash_position %>`
```

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous - change it to `promise = $.ajax({url: "/payment_schedules/cash_position.json"})` and then update the chart when the data is actually loaded `promise.done (event, data, status, xhr) -> window.lineChart.setData(data)`

Comment: Also please add the relevant code from your controller.

Comment: Ok I have added the PaymentSchedule controller code for `cash_position` to the post. I've incorporated the `.done` with no luck yet.

Comment: Your controller only fetches a single `PaymentSchedule` - why would you expect a single `PaymentSchedule` to magically become an array of hashes? It makes no sense.

Comment: This is because my ajax request goes directly to the .json url, which fetches the right data but parses it with &quot and =&gt pieces. So I don't have much going on in the controller.  So I figured going straight to the json url would give me what I need, if I can get it to parse correctly.

Comment: I've also just now added my json.erb view template to the post. The result of .cash_position is the array of hashes from the model method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@papirtiger is correct as to the controller code, but we ended up using JQuery's `deferred.then()` method to get this to work:

`coffeescript
$.ajax(
  url: '/payment_schedules/cash_position.json'
  dataType: 'json'
).then (data) ->
  window.lineChart.setData(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need / want a view for rendering JSON.
Basically JSON views are slow since you are concatenating strings, vs converting Ruby objects which is done in highly optimized C code.

Just use `render json:`

```
def cash_position
    @payment_schedules = PaymentSchedule.find
    respond_to do |f|
      f.json { render json: @payment_schedule.cash_position }
    end
end
```

For more complex requirements you might want to use the awesome gem [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), it is also really easy to test.

Also your ajax handler is a bit off (sorry I'm rubbish at CS).

```
$('.update-percent').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
   // data in this scope is whatever the previous ajax call returned.
   // masking the variable is bound to lead to confusion.

   var promise = $.ajax({
      url: "/payment_schedules/cash_position.json",
      dataType: 'json'
   });
   promise.done(function(cash_positions){
     // this is just an example of how you can use callback chaining
     // to process the data.
     return $.map(cash_positions, function(cp){
     });
   });
   promise.done(function(continuation){
     window.lineChart.setData(continuation);
   });
});
```

If you use a pattern like the above you can avoid tainting your API with whatever data structure requirements the graph has.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this. It's not quite there yet but I am going to work on it some more tomorrow with my coding partner, using your answer as guidance. Will report back.